# Find first and second element in list C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, list

Here's my program for implementing a list in C++. I type elements untill 0. Program shows me first element correctly but second is wrong. I probably make errors in second condition

```
if (p -> next == first) {
    secondElement = first -> data;
}
```

[image]

. Can you say what is wrong with it. Thanks

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

int firstElement;
int secondElement;

int main()
{
    Node *first = 0;
    Node *p;

    cout << "Enter a list" << endl;
    int i;
    while (true) {

        cin >> i;
        if (i == 0) break;


        p = new Node;
        p -> data = i;


        p -> next = first;

        if (first == 0) {
            first = p;
            firstElement = first -> data;
        }

        if (p -> next == first) {
            secondElement = first -> data;
        }       

        first = p;

    }

    cout << "First element is: " << firstElement << endl;
    cout << "Second element is: " << secondElement << endl;
    cout << "List: ";

    p = first;
    while (p) {
        cout << p -> data << " ";
        p = p -> next;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use std::list ?

Comment: it's my task. I have to do it manually

Comment: I believe it's printing first and second element same.

Comment: Are you trying to get last in, first out behaviour?

Comment: Some general comments: Don't use `new`/`delete`, use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` instead. I see you're already avoiding `delete`, but that just means you're leaking. Don't use `0` as a null pointer constant. Use `nullptr` instead. In real program one should that input operations like `cin >> i` succeed and that failures are handled appropriately. Using `"\n"` instead of `endl` should be preferred. `endl` does something extra that generally not needed. include iostream like `#include <iostream>` instead of using quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this (I just edited your while loop):

```
while (true) {

    cin >> i;
    if (i == 0) break;


    p = new Node;
    p -> data = i;
    p -> next = 0;

    if (first != 0 && first->next == 0)
        secondElement = p->data;

    p -> next = first;

    if (first == 0) {
        first = p;
        firstElement = first -> data;
    }

    first = p;

}
```

Hope it is what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

Each time through the loop you're setting the pointer of the element to the first.

```
p -> next = first;
```

Then in the check for the second element you're checking whether the pointer is set to the first, which it always is.

```
 if (p -> next == first) // This is always true
```

You'll have to use some different check to see whether it's the second entry in the list, like:

```
if (p->next && !p->next->next) // only true second time around
{
    secondElement = p -> data; // also note the change here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p -> next = first;
......
enter code here
 if (p -> next == first) {  //it's always true here
```

you should have had

```
 if (p -> next == 0) {
```